# Field editor breaks grid

Tags: add-on, grid, database-error, field-editor

I use the "field editor" plugin a lot.

But it doesn't seem to work with the new grid fieldtype.

So it now just messes up channel fields with grid.
I now can't delete the messed up field group.

```
A Database Error Occurred
Error Number: 1091
Can't DROP 'field_id_21'; check that column/key exists
ALTER TABLE `exp_channel_data` DROP `field_id_21`
Filename: libraries/api/Api_channel_fields.php
Line Number: 495
```

How do I delete the fieldgroup anyway?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it will be enough to delete field record in exp_channel_fields table.

Go to EE CP SQL manager (CP Home > Tools > Data > SQL Manager > Database Query Form) or phpMyAdmin or any other mysql manager:

```
DELETE FROM exp_channel_fields where field_id = 21;
```

if you want to be sure that any pieces of your grid field was removed, execute query bellow line-by-line. Not all of them give you successful message, because not all records exist.

```
ALTER TABLE exp_channel_data DROP field_ft_21;
ALTER TABLE exp_channel_data DROP field_id_21;
DELETE FROM exp_channel_fields where field_id = 21;
DELETE FROM exp_grid_columns where field_id = 21;
DROP TABLE exp_channel_grid_field_21;
```